# Scan for new Contract/Token

Tags: contract-debugging, binance

I am trying to find a way to use the JSON-RPC calls to scan for new tokens on the BEP-20 Binance chain.

I cannot find any documentation or information regarding this.

Comment: Did you try using events?

Comment: not sure about what you mean, do you have any links for this.

Comment: In Ethereum there's [eth_getlogs](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_getlogs) to retrieve logs from transaction receipts. Tokens compliant with [ERC-20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) have to generate `Transfer` events for every token transfer.